# NullInjectorError when using inject() in runInContext

Tags: angular, angular-injector

The following code is triggering `NullInjectorError` when i'm calling `@inject()` in `runInContext`.
This does not happen if the service is `providedIn: 'root'` or passed in the module `providers`.

Any idea why ?

```
@Injectable()
class Service {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [Service],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  public constructor(service: Service, injector: EnvironmentInjector) {
    console.log(service); // OK
    console.log(inject(Service)); //OK

    setTimeout(() => {
      injector.runInContext(() => {
        console.log(inject(Service)); //KO
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yccqgi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [Angular#47566](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/47566), this is currently as design but could be improved.

So wait & see.